# rVest: How to extract values (ignoring children)

Tags: r, xml, parent-child, rvest

I would like to extract the values from a webpage, but for certain xml structures, I seem to get out aggregate values.

```
data
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <span class="match">tusinde<span class="super">1</span></span>
```

If I extract the text I get:

```
data %>% html_text()
tusinde1
```

What I want is:

```
tusinde
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more background on the general question and a reproducible example, it is difficult to come with a solution that works beyond the particular example you give.

The following code, for instance, solves your problem, but I don't know how well in generalizes beyond that particular case.

```
data <- "<span class=\"match\">tusinde<span class=\"super\">1</span></span>"

out <- data %>% read_xml() %>% xml_contents() 

as.character(out[1])
```

Gives you:

```
[1] "tusinde"
```